# Send Email based on Dropdownlist.SelectedItem & Also Insert the Dropdownlist.SelectedValue into Database

Tags: asp.net, sql, email, drop-down-menu

I don't know how to go about this. I have a web form with dropdown list, named Recruiter. I have two SQL tables named Perm_Commision_Lookup & UserList.

One of the tables contain **email** and the other does not. The Perm_Commision_Lookup  table does not contain recruiter's email, so I decided to Inner Join it with UserList table which contain recruiter emails. The LookupValue (Recruiter's display name) column from the Perm_Commision_Lookup table is what's displayed to the end user and the pk_LookupID column is the one that's inserted into the database.

What I want to achieve is this: When a user select let's say "John Doe" from the Recruiter dropdown list, I want to send out an email to John Doe alerting him that a form has been submitted and at the same time insert the selected value (pk_LookupID) into the database.

I see that the dropdown list has two field named:   **DataTextField="LookupValue"** and  **DataValueField="pk_LookupID**  but how to get the User_Email is my major problem. Below is my SQL select...So far I can do a SQL INNER JOIN...which shown below and also I can display multiple columns into dropdown list...I'm also trying SQLDataReader but I'm just stop with how to get it done.

```
SELECT  Perm_Commision_Lookup.pk_LookupID, Perm_Commision_Lookup.LookupValue, UserList.User_Email 

FROM Perm_Commision_Lookup

INNER JOIN UserList ON Perm_Commision_Lookup.LookupUserName = UserList.GM_Username
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your reply! Correct! It's linked via LookupUserName. That's what I have as for now...but still have the problem

Public Sub BindDropDownListData()
        ' connection string
        Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString

```
    Using mySqlConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Try
            ' open the Sql connection
            mySqlConnection.Open()

            ' Sql Command query to retrieve pk_LookupID, LookupValue, GM_Username, User_Email
            Dim mySqlCommand As New SqlCommand(" SELECT  Perm_Commision_Lookup.pk_LookupID, Perm_Commision_Lookup.LookupValue, UserList.GM_Username, UserList.User_Email FROM Perm_Commision_Lookup INNER JOIN UserList ON Perm_Commision_Lookup.LookupUserName  = UserList.GM_Username   order by LookupValue asc", mySqlConnection)

            Dim mySqlDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter()

            mySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = mySqlCommand
            Dim myDataSet As New DataSet
            ' mySqlConnection.Open()


            ' Sql Data Reader to fetch the records row by row in forward direction.
            Dim myDataReader As SqlDataReader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()

            'Perm_Commision_Lookup
            If myDataReader.HasRows Then


                ' read each row fetched using DataReader
                While myDataReader.Read()
                    Dim li As New ListItem()

                    'email = myDataReader("User_Email")

                    li.Value = myDataReader("pk_LookupID")
                    li.Text = myDataReader("LookupValue")

                    DropDownList1.Items.Add(li)

                End While
            End If
            myDataReader.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Label1.Text = ex.Message
        Finally
            ' close the Sql Connection
            mySqlConnection.Close()
        End Try

        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Please Select Recruiter", ""))
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: In that case you should use LookupUserName as the Value field for your Dropdown. Then follow what I said in my previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

1: Use dropdown selectedIndexChanged event.

2: Inside the handler query the database to get the Email and send email.

3: You can selected lookupname from dropdown in the SelectedIndexChanged handler like myddl.SelectedItem.Text or you can get lookupid like myddl.SelectedValue.

From your query it seems your tables are linked via LookupUserName correct or is it LookupId?

And [this might help.](http://www.dotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/dropdownlisiindatagrid05082007024918AM/dropdownlisiindatagrid.aspx)